# Populate inputs when selecting name

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

This is my invoice form. I want to populate title according to select coming from database option field. How do I get the values from the Client database to populate title in the invoice form. Thanks.

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.invoices.store') }}" method="post">  

     {{ csrf_field() }}

     <div class="row">

           <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group">

                <label for="invoicenumber">Invoice Number</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="invoice_no" id="number">
                <span class="alert-danger" id="number-feedback"></span>


              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="client">Client</label><br>
               <select name="client" id="client_id" class="form-control">
                  <option value="select">Select Client</option>
                   @foreach($clients as $client)
                       <option id="option" value="{{ $client-> id|$client->name }}">{{ $client->name }}</option>
                   @endforeach
               </select>


              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Title">Title</label><br>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title">
                <span class="alert-danger" id="title-feedback"></span>
              </div>
           </div>
```

My route

```
 Route::post('/populate', 'InvoiceController@populate');
```

my ajax request

```
$(document).on('change', '#client_id', function(event){

    var id = $("#client_id").find(":selected").text();



$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/populate',
        data: {id: id, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        success: function( data ) {
           //$('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #refresh');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

an this is where I am struggling most with the logic

```
    public function populate(Request $request){

    $client =Client::find($request->id);


    }
```

this is the data I want to fetch from Client table to populate invoice table when I select client name.

```
 Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('company');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('info');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Consider using Vue and Axios (deals with ajax requests) that is shipped with Laravel. Though, your populate() function should return the $client, why isn't it? I suppose that is why you having any data show up in your browser's console when you select a client.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am getting the id, that’s not the problem. The problem is that I am struggling with. The logic to return the title to populate input in my invoice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Spacemudd said

```
return $client;
```

is missing in the populate function after the

```
$client =Client::find($request->id);
```

after that you can see your data in a console of a browser.